How to Split mysql Column Data using JSONSTRING
I have a Column in MYSQL table with the following values
"acc":"0","alarm":"02","batl":"6","bats":"1","cellid":"0","defense":"1","gpslev":"15","gsmlev":"3","lac":"0","mcc":"0"

I want to split the data using JSONSTRING, I have the following code thus far but I cannot populate the $jsonString with the data
// Query: Fetch the required data from MySQL table
$sql = "SELECT params FROM gs_objects WHERE imei = '863281047502101'";
$result = $connection->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// Fetch the row as an associative array
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

// Populate JSON string using fetched data
$jsonData = [
'params' => $row['params'],
];

// Convert associative array to JSON string
$jsonString = json_encode($jsonData);

// Output JSON string
echo "Populated JSON String: " . PHP_EOL;
echo $jsonString;

} else {
echo "No data found for the given query.";
}
// The provided JSON string
$jsonString = ***I need to Populate this with the column Data***

// Decode the JSON string into an associative array
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);

// Check if decoding was successful
if ($data === null) {
echo "Invalid JSON string.";
exit;
}

// Extract specific values
$acc = $data['acc'];
$alarm = $data['alarm'];                                        
$gpslev = $data['gpslev'];
$bats = $data['bats'];

In the echo $jsonString; I get the following value:
{\"acc\":\"0\",\"alarm\":\"02\",\"batl\":\"6\"...........}

I need the above value without the \ to be placed into
// The provided JSON string
$jsonString =

Section of my code

echo $jsonString; after json_decode()

I understood the request/question as to just literally remove the slashes '\' on the $jsonString.
You may do so with str_replace().
$test = '{\"acc\":\"0\",\"alarm\":\"02\",\"batl\":\"6\"...........}';
$removed = str_replace('\\', '', $test);

Checking the result
var_dump($removed);
string(46) "{"acc":"0","alarm":"02","batl":"6"...........}" // the output

The output is still a string.

check the string output after json_decode()
$strjson = '"acc":"0","alarm":"02","batl":"6","bats":"1","cellid":"0","defense":"1","gpslev":"15","gsmlev":"3","lac":"0","mcc":"0"';

$jsonString = json_encode($strjson);

echo  json_decode($jsonString);

Result
"acc":"0","alarm":"02","batl":"6","bats":"1","cellid":"0","defense":"1","gpslev":"15","gsmlev":"3","lac":"0","mcc":"0"

